# Javascript: adding a key-value pair to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I noticed that I can add a key value pair to an array (not an object, an array).

```
var a = [];       // create the array
a[0] = "test";    // conventionally setting an index of 0 to a value
a["foo"] = "bar"; // this actually sets a "key" of the array to "bar"
```

If I try to get the value of `a.foo` or `a["foo"], I simply get "bar". No errors raised.

I know that a Javascript Array is actually an object, but with special rules, but it feels weird that this doesn't throw an error.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

**Is there an actual use case where this is ok to do? What is common practice around this fact?**

Comment: You can add props to any object, like array or even function. It's not a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now try this:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
[ '0', 'length', 'foo' ]
> a.length
1
```

Welcome to JavaScript! It's such a wonderful place...

Yes, you can create named properties on an array. No, you probably shouldn't. They won't be counted in `Array.length`, and most developers who read your code will be experiencing a moment of confusion that is unlikely to lead to a positive outcome.

If you need a named property, use a (non-array) object.

Comment: Thanks, I like the example of length, makes it clear that it is probably not a good idea. However, I'd think it's ok to use in cases where you know what you're doing, and other options aren't optimal either?

Comment: I would think those occasions would be very rare, but sure. I guess you have to ask yourself, "will I still understand this code when I come back to it six months later?" :)